# Dependency in custom Angular library is not found when consuming application is building

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I have a custom angular library that I wrote and I want to use it in an application. When I try to build my application, it says it cannot resolve a library that my library is using.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome' in 'C:\test\src\app'
   resolve '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome' in 'C:\test\src\app'
   Parsed request is a module
      using description file: C:\test\package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
```

Inside my library, I have @fortawesome as a dependency in both package.json in my library. From my understanding, this should force my application to download @fortawesome correct?

Why is it that my application build looks for @fortawesome in the application's node_module instead of the library?

Comment: did u already publish ur library?  and ur @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome is included in package.json in application ?

Comment: fortawesome is not included in my application. I am trying to force it as a download so other users of my library will not need to add it to their package.json. I thought that was the whole point of putting fortawesome within the inner package.json